# El botón Actualizar de mi sistema JavaWeb con JPA no funciona

Tags: java, mvc, jpa, aplicación-web

Lo que me pasa es que ya tengo el botón hecho en el jsp; tengo la acción del botón en el controlador ya creada; tengo el metodo de actualizarCliente en una clase que retorna en el metodo actualizar de la persistencia; y por ultimo tengo el metodo de actualizar en el PersistanceController ya creado, pero aun así teniendo todo esto, el botón de actualizar no realiza nada. Se ejecuta, pero no realiza nada.

Mi sistema esta hecho en JavaWeb utilizando el patron MVC, y JPA para interactuar con la Base de datos.

El siguiente código es mi sistema y lo que he probado para que funcione pero aun así no sigue funcionando el Botón de Actualizar:

El siguiente código es el JSP donde esta el botón de Actualizar:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Sección | Clientes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="card col-sm-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="Controlador?menu=Cliente" method="POST"> <!-- FORMULARIO PARA INGRESAR UN NUEVO CLIENTE -->
                        <!-- Campo para el Dni -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Dni</label>
                            <input type="text" value="${not empty cliente ? cliente.getDni() : ''}" name="txtDni" class="form-control"> <%-- value="${cliente.getDni()}" --%>
                            <!-- Mensaje de error para el campo Telefono -->
                            <div class="text-danger" id="mensajeErrorDni">
                                ${mensajeErrorDni}
                                <script>
                                    // Función para ocultar el mensaje de error después de 7 segundos
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        document.getElementById('mensajeErrorDni').style.display = 'none';
                                    }, 20000); // Duración en milisegundos del mensaje de error
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Campo para los Nombres -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Nombres</label>
                            <input type="text" value="${not empty cliente ? cliente.getNom() : ''}" name="txtNombres" class="form-control"> <%-- value="${cliente.getNom()}" --%>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Campo para el Telefono -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Telefono</label>
                            <input type="text" value="${not empty cliente ? cliente.getTel() : ''}" name="txtTel" class="form-control"> <%-- value="${cliente.getTel()}" --%>
                            <!-- Mensaje de error para el campo Telefono -->
                            <div class="text-danger" id="mensajeErrorTelefono">
                                ${mensajeErrorTelefono}
                                <script>
                                    // Función para ocultar el mensaje de error después de 7 segundos
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        document.getElementById('mensajeErrorTelefono').style.display = 'none';
                                    }, 20000); // Duración en milisegundos del mensaje de error
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Campo para la Direccion -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Direccion</label>
                            <input type="text" value="${not empty cliente ? cliente.getDir() : ''}" name="txtDir" class="form-control"> <%-- value="${cliente.getDir()}" --%>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Campo para el Estado -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Estado</label>
                            <input type="text" value="${not empty cliente ? cliente.getEstado() : ''}" name="txtEstado" class="form-control"> <%-- value="${cliente.getEstado()}" --%>
                            <!-- Mensaje de error para el campo Estado -->
                            <div class="text-danger" id="mensajeErrorEstado">
                                ${mensajeErrorEstado}
                                <script>
                                    // Función para ocultar el mensaje de error después de 7 segundos
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        document.getElementById('mensajeErrorEstado').style.display = 'none';
                                    }, 20000); // Duración en milisegundos del mensaje de error
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <!-- BOTONES PARA GUARDAR y CANCELAR GUARDADO; ACTUALIZAR Y CANCELAR EDICIÓN -->
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <!-- Mostrar el botón de "Guardar" solo cuando no se está editando un cliente -->
                                <button type="submit" name="accion" style="margin-right: 6px" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de AGREGAR este cliente?')">Guardar</button>
                                <button type="submit" name="accion" style="margin-right: 6px" value="cancelarGuardado" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de CANCELAR el guardado del cliente?')">Cancelar</button>
                                <button type="submit" name="accion" style="margin-right: 6px" value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de actualizar este cliente?')">Actualizar</button>
                                <button type="submit" name="accion" value="cancelarEdicion" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de cancelar la edición?')">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <table Class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="text-left"> 
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>DNI</th>
                            <th>NOMBRES</th>
                            <th>TELEFONO</th>
                            <th>DIRECCION</th>
                            <th>ESTADO</th>
                            <th>ACCIONES</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="cl" items="${clientes}"> <!--El atributo clientes se esta enviando desde el controlador.-->
                            <tr> <!-- ARROJAMIENTO DE LOS DATOS DE LOS CLIENTES AGREGADOS -->
                                <td>${cl.getId()}</td>
                                <td>${cl.getDni()}</td>
                                <td>${cl.getNom()}</td>
                                <td>${cl.getTel()}</td>
                                <td>${cl.getDir()}</td>
                                <td>${cl.getEstado()}</td>
                                <td class="d-flex"> <!-- td PARA LOS BOTONES DE EDITAR Y ELIMINAR CLIENTES -->
                                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Editar&id=${cl.getId()}">Editar</a> <!-- onclick="mostrarCancelar()"  -->
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 6px" onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de ELIMINAR este cliente?')" href="Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Delete&id=${cl.getId()}">Eliminar</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <!-- MENSAJE EXITO EN LAS ACCIONES -->
        <!-- Mensaje de éxito al realizar una acción --> 
        <% String mensajeCorrecto = (String) request.getAttribute("mensajeCorrecto");
            if (mensajeCorrecto != null) {%>
        <div id="mensajeCorrecto" class="alert alert-success text-center" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);" role="alert">
            <%= mensajeCorrecto%>
        </div>
        <script>
            // Función para ocultar el mensaje de éxito después de 6 segundos
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('mensajeCorrecto').style.display = 'none';
            }, 7000); // Duración en milisegundos del mensaje de éxito
        </script>
        <%}%>
        <!-- MENSAJE EXITO EN LAS ACCIONES DE CANCELAR-->
        <!-- Mensaje de éxito al realizar una cancelacion --> 
        <% String mensajeCancelar = (String) request.getAttribute("mensajeCancelar");
            if (mensajeCancelar != null) {%>
        <div id="mensajeCancelar" class="alert alert-warning text-center" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);" role="alert">
            <%= mensajeCancelar%>
        </div>
        <script>
            // Función para ocultar el mensaje de éxito después de 6 segundos
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('mensajeCancelar').style.display = 'none';
            }, 7000); // Duración en milisegundos del mensaje de éxito
        </script>
        <%}%>
        <!-- MENSAJE DE ERROR EN LAS ACCIONES -->
        <!-- Mensaje de error al realizar una accion-->            
        <% String mensajeError = (String) request.getAttribute("mensajeError");
            if (mensajeError != null) {%>
        <div id="mensajeError" class="alert alert-danger text-center" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);" role="alert">
            <%= mensajeError%>
        </div>
        <script>
            // Función para ocultar el mensaje de éxito después de 6 segundos
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('mensajeError').style.display = 'none';
            }, 8000); // Duración en milisegundos del mensaje de éxito
        </script>
        <%}%>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

El siguiente código es el servlet Controlador donde esta la acción del botón de Actualizar:

```
package Controlador;

import Modelo.Cliente;
import Modelo.ClienteDAO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "Controlador", urlPatterns = {"/Controlador"})
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {

Cliente cl = new Cliente();
ClienteDAO cdao = new ClienteDAO();

public Controlador() {
        PersistanceController.makeEntitiMF();
    }

   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
        String menu = request.getParameter("menu");
        String accion = request.getParameter("accion");

        if (menu != null && menu.equals("Principal")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Principal.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

//MENU CLIENTES
        if (menu.equals("Cliente")) {
            switch (accion) {
                //Acción de Listar para listar la lista de clientes
                case "Listar":
                    List lista = cdao.getListaClientes();//cdao.listar();
                    request.setAttribute("clientes", lista); //Aquí se esta definiendo clientes como un atributo del arrays lista. 
                    break;

                //Acción del boton Actualizar para actualizar un Cliente
                case "Actualizar":
                    String dni1 = request.getParameter("txtDni");
                    String nom1 = request.getParameter("txtNombres");
                    String tel1 = request.getParameter("txtTel");
                    String dir1 = request.getParameter("txtDir");
                    String est1 = request.getParameter("txtEstado");

                   //Se le asigan al objeto cl (Cliente) los datos ingresados por el usuario
                    cl.setDni(dni1);
                    cl.setNom(nom1);
                    cl.setTel(tel1);
                    cl.setDir(dir1);
                    cl.setEstado(est1);

                    // Validar si hay campos vacíos.
                    if (dni1.isEmpty() || nom1.isEmpty() || tel1.isEmpty() || dir1.isEmpty() || est1.isEmpty()) {
                        // Si hay campos vacios, se muestra un mensaje de error al usuario.
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeError", "ERROR, Se debe llenar todos los campos para actualizar un cliente.");
                        // Se guarda el objeto cl (Cliente) en el atributo "cliente" para mantener los datos ingreados en el formulario si hay un error
                        request.setAttribute("cliente", cl);
                        // Se recarga la pagina con la acción de "Listar".
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Validar el DNI ingresado
                    if (dni1.length() > 10) {
                        // Si el DNI tiene más de 10 dígitos, mostrar un mensaje de error en el campo de DNI
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeErrorDni", "Hay un ERROR en el DNI");
                        // Mensaje de error en la interfaz por DNI erroneo
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeError", "DNI erróneo. Por favor actualize el Dni a con un Dni valido.");
                        // Se guarda el objeto cl (Cliente) en el atributo "cliente" para mantener los datos ingreados en el formulario si hay un error
                        request.setAttribute("cliente", cl);
                        // Se recarga la pagina con la acción de "Listar".
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Validar el telefono ingresado
                    if (tel1.length() > 15) {
                        // Mensaje error para el campo de teléfono
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeErrorTelefono", "Hay un ERROR en el Teléfono");
                        // Mensaje de error en la interfaz por teléfono erroneo
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeError", "Telefono erróneo. Por favor actualize el Telefono a con un Telefono valido.");
                        // Se guarda el objeto cl (Cliente) en el atributo "cliente" para mantener los datos ingreados en el formulario si hay un error
                        request.setAttribute("cliente", cl);
                        
                        // Se recarga la pagina con la acción de "Listar".
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Validar el estado ingresado
                    if (!est1.equals("1") && !est1.equals("2")) {
                        // Si el estado no es 1 ni 2, se muestra un mensaje de error en el campo de estado
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeErrorEstado", "Hay un ERROR en el Estado");
                        // Mensaje de error en la interfaz por Estado erróneo
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeError", "El estado debe ser 1 (Cliente activo) o 2 (para Cliente inactivo).");
                        // Se guarda el objeto cl (Cliente) en el atributo "cliente" para mantener los datos ingreados en el formulario si hay un error
                        request.setAttribute("cliente", cl);
                        // Se recarga la pagina con la acción de "Listar".
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Si no hay errores, se procede a actualizar el cliente
                    if (request.getAttribute("mensajeError") == null) {
                        cdao.actualizarCliente(cl);
                        //request.setAttribute("editarCliente", false);
                        // Actualización exitosa, redireccionar a la página de listado de clientes
                        request.setAttribute("mensajeCorrecto", "¡Se ha actualizado el Cliente con éxito!");
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
                        return; //Se retorna para salir del metodo de actualizar 
                    }
                    
                    // Se recarga la pagina con la acción de "Listar".
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Cliente&accion=Listar").forward(request, response);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Clientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controlador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controlador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

El siguiente código es la Clase de ClienteDAO:

```
package Modelo;

import Controlador.PersistanceController;

public class ClienteDAO {

   public ClienteDAO() {

   }

//Actualizar Cliente
    public boolean actualizarCliente(Cliente cliente) { 
        return PersistanceController.actualizar(cliente);
    }
}
```

El siguiente código es el método de actualizar de la PersistanceController que se utiliza para actualizar entidades (Este es un metodo generico usado para actualizar).

```
package Controlador;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class PersistanceController implements Serializable {

   public static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
   public static EntityManager em = null;
   public static String puName = "SistemaVentasTaniaSoftPU";

   public static void makeEntitiMF() throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(puName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

   public static void closeEntitiMF() {
        if (emf != null) {
            if (emf.isOpen()) {
                emf.close();
            }
        }

   }

   public static void initEM() {
        makeEntitiMF();
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
   }

   public PersistanceController() {
        makeEntitiMF();
   }

public static <T> void actualizarEntidades(T entidadActualizada) {
        initEM();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            // Recuperar la entidad existente de la base de datos
            T entidadExistente = (T) em.find(entidadActualizada.getClass(), obtenerId(entidadActualizada));
            // Actualizar los campos de la entidadExistente con los valores de entidadActualizada
            actualizarCampos(entidadExistente, entidadActualizada);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
    
   public static <T> boolean actualizar(T entidadActualizada) {
        initEM();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            //em.refresh(entidadActualizada);
            actualizarEntidades(entidadActualizada); // Llamar al método genérico para preparar la entidad actualizada
            em.merge(entidadActualizada); // Realizar la operación de merge con la entidad actualizada
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

   private static <T> Serializable obtenerId(T entidad) {
        try {
            Method getIdMethod = entidad.getClass().getMethod("getId");
            return (Serializable) getIdMethod.invoke(entidad);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

   private static <T> void actualizarCampos(T entidadExistente, T entidadActualizada) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] campos = entidadActualizada.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field campo : campos) {
            campo.setAccessible(true);
            Object valor = campo.get(entidadActualizada);
            if (valor != null) {
                campo.set(entidadExistente, valor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

¿Que solución me podrían dar para que este bendito botón de actualizar funcione correctamente?.